# Mysql : Get COUNT(B.column) as B_count and Left Join B where B_count not equals to 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get rows where the count column `b_count` is not `0`

```
SELECT `tags`.*, 
       Count(`album_picture_tag`.`tag_id`) AS `c_count` 
FROM   `tags` 
       INNER JOIN `album_picture_tag` 
               ON `tags`.`id` = `album_picture_tag`.`tag_id` 
WHERE  `tags`.`id` = 16 
       AND `c_count` != 0;
```

but it keeps giving me the error:
`#1054 - Unknown column 'c_count' in 'where clause'`

which part am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use having clause with group by and use expression instead of alias name

```
SELECT `tags`.id, 
       Count(`album_picture_tag`.`tag_id`) AS `c_count` 
FROM   `tags` 
       INNER JOIN `album_picture_tag` 
               ON `tags`.`id` = `album_picture_tag`.`tag_id` 
WHERE  `tags`.`id` = 16 
group by `tags`.id
having Count(`album_picture_tag`.`tag_id`) != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `group by`:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       COUNT(apt.tag_id) AS c_count
FROM tags t INNER JOIN
     album_picture_tag apt
     ON t.id = apt.tag_id 
WHERE t.id = 16 
GROUP BY t.id;
```

The `INNER JOIN` requires that there be a match.  Hence, the count will never be `0`.  Well, if could be if `tag_id` could be `NULL`.  But it can't be because it is used for the `JOIN`.

Note that I introduced table aliases, which make the query simpler to write and to read.  I also removed all the extraneous backticks.  They just clutter the query.